# How to set up group_concat_max_length permanently in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

How to set up group concat max length permanently in Mysql?

While setting group concat max length:

```
SET group_concat_max_len=102400
```

At the time it is set, but after restarting the server, it shows its default value 1024 again.

Comment: add right tags to your question please

Answer (score 2):

Edit my.cnf file and add `group_concat_max_len=102400` under [mysqld] section. Then restart mysql service and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it to MySQL deamon via param:

--group_concat_max_len=xxx